# loopedslider.js not working in wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I'm working on a wordpress site that has loopedslider on it. the slider has suddenly stopped working and I can't seem to find any error. I'm not really versed in jquery, so I don't know what might have gone wrong. Thanks for the help. The url http://goo.gl/pWj0f .

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is related to changes in jQuery, around the 1.8 version. This should be the fix.

Edit line 164 of loopedSlider.js.

From:

```
jQuery(pagination+'[rel="' + (t) + '"]',obj).parent().addClass('active');
```

To:

```
jQuery('[rel="' + (t) + '"]',obj).parent().addClass('active');
```

For a full thread on this issue:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/slider-issue-with-photoria-jquery-error

Comment: thanks. I ended up using one of the other sliders, so can't test your answer. But I appreciate the effort.